# How do I get more granular LinkedIn user information using linkedin gem and omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, devise, linkedin-api, omniauth

I want to get a user's position information from their LinkedIn profile (company name, title, etc), but I can't get anything more than basic profile information (id, name, email, headline, and image).  I'm guessins this is just a syntax thing since I'm requesting access to all fields upon user's authentication.

from user.rb

```
    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.name = auth.info.name
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.headline = auth.info.headline
        **user.company = auth.info.company**
        user.avatar = auth.info.image
        user.password = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(n=6)
        user.save!    
    end
```

from devise.rb

```
  config.omniauth :linkedin, "abcdefghijk", "abcdefghijk", 
  # :scope => 'r_basicprofile r_emailaddress rw_nus r_fullprofile r_contactinfo r_network rw_company_admin',
  # :fields =>
  :scope => 'r_basicprofile r_emailaddress rw_nus r_fullprofile r_contactinfo r_network rw_company_admin', 
  :fields => ["id", "email-address", "first-name", "last-name", 
                  "headline", "industry", "picture-url", "public-profile-url", 
                  "location", "connections", "skills", "date-of-birth", "phone-numbers",        
                  "educations", "three-current-positions" ]
```

Do I need to add fields to devise.rb or am I being an idiot and formatting `user.company = auth.info.company` wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to get the company ID (for which the user is admin) ?

Answer (score 0):

[edit]
okay, found it. The devise.rb field definition is wrong. (Probably outdated, I used the same and it was copied from somewhere.)

Correct name now is just "positions", not "three-current-positions"

After that, `auth.extra.info.positions` becomes available (with these params: https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/fields/positions)

Answer (score -1):

The format for accessing user info id is:

```
user.name = auth["info"]["name"]
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the OP's question.